# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040150 (REGDB_E_READREGDB)

Tags: powershell, remote-access, windows-server-2008-r2

While executing the following script on server1:

```
powershell.exe invoke-command -computerName server2 -scriptblock{cmd.exe "/c d:\scripts\start_SXXX_S012.bat"}
```

we'll get the following error (on server1), but only if no user is logged on at the server server2:

> The shell cannot be started. A failure occurred during initialization:
>   Could not read key from registry (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040150
>   (REGDB_E_READREGDB))

The `invoke-command` (and the following work on server ssql012) runs well, if anybody is logged on on server2. server1 is a WinServer 2012R2, server2 a WinServer 2012.

Any ideas on how to fix the problem?

Comment: I received this same message installing Amazon's CodeDeploy Update Agent (automated on an auto scaling group).

My error description however is:

Failed to connect to server. Error: 0x80040150

I doubt I will have time to do so, but much (all?) of PowerShell is open source, perhaps search the source for the more specific (or perhaps more generic) Win32 errors that are happening behind the scenes.